# Android: Access activity context from TimerTask

Tags: android, kotlin, android-context, timertask

Is there anyway to access the activity context from a TimerTask object? Here is what I have so far, but I'm getting errors while trying to access *this(Activity context)* from the TimerTask object. The below code is contained in an Activity:

```
    Timer().schedule(object : TimerTask() {
        override fun run() {
            runOnUiThread(object : Runnable {
                override fun run() {
                    startActivity(Intent(this, HomeScreenActivity::class.java))
                    finish()
                }
            })
        }
    }, 2)
```

As you can see, I tried running the task on

> runOnUiThread(...)

but I still can't access the Activity context. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` refers to the `this` of the most immediate enclosing function, which in this case is your Runnable. Use `this@MyActivity` to specify your outer activity class, where `MyActivity` is the name of that class.

It is necessary to use `runOnUiThread` not for the reason you tried it, but because you can't start an activity from a background thread.

Incidentally, Kotlin provides some extension functions and SAM conversions that could make your code more readable:

```
Timer().schedule(2000L) {
    runOnUiThread {
        startActivity(Intent(this@MyActivity, HomeScreenActivity::class.java))
        finish()
    }
}
```

Comment: Solved my problem. Thanks!